# ASP.Net SafeHandle - tasks and examples

Tags: asp.net, safehandle

I want to understand how to work with unmanaged resources and when I need the SafeHandle class. What can be the problem statement when you can say: "Oh, here I need the SafeHandle class!"?

I would be grateful for links to articles, examples, explanations

Answer (score 0):

I think [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.safehandle?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-6.0) is pretty clear in definition:

> The SafeHandle class provides critical finalization of handle
> resources, preventing handles from being reclaimed prematurely by
> garbage collection and from being recycled by Windows to reference
> unintended unmanaged objects. Before the .NET Framework version 2.0,
> all operating system handles could only be encapsulated in the IntPtr
> managed wrapper object.
>
> The SafeHandle class contains a finalizer that ensures that the handle
> is closed and is guaranteed to run, even during unexpected AppDomain
> unloads when a host may not trust the consistency of the state of the
> AppDomain.
>
> For more information about the benefits of using a SafeHandle, see
> Safe Handles and Critical Finalization.
>
> This class is abstract because you cannot create a generic handle. To
> implement SafeHandle, you must create a derived class. To create
> SafeHandle derived classes, you must know how to create and free an
> operating system handle. This process is different for different
> handle types because some use CloseHandle, while others use more
> specific methods such as UnmapViewOfFile or FindClose. For this
> reason, you must create a derived class of SafeHandle for each
> operating system handle type; such as MySafeRegistryHandle,
> MySafeFileHandle, and MySpecialSafeFileHandle. Some of these derived
> classes are prewritten and provided for you in the
> Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles namespace.

Comment: thanks, but that's too general. In my practice, I use using and IDispose to work with connection strings  and files. And I never met SafeHandle in the projects I work with